# Filter data set by month

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using an embedded data source of type SharePoint List.

I use a parameter that a user can modify that will filter the data set by the month. I've seen a few examples but they all either use a SQL query or only filters on the exact day rather than the month.

I added a parameter `ParamMonth` and gave it the data type of Date/Time. I can see this adds a drop down box to my report which is exactly what I want. Ideally, I would like to add the name of all 12 months or something similar, but I don't know how that will work out when the data exceeds a single year. Now, that I've got my Report Parameter added, I need to add it to my dataset to filter on. This is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way could be creating a parameter type `Integer` and set all months in `Available Values` tab as follows (I just set five months for example).

[image]

Then go to the `DataSet Properties` / `Filter` tab and use the below settings.

[image]

For expression use:

```
=MONTH(Fields!Date.Value)
```

Where `Date` is the field that you will use to filter by month. In `Value` you have to use:

```
=Parameters!Month.Value
```

**UPDATE:** Provide year selection.

The best approach for this is getting the available values from a DataSet, in this case your SP list.

Just create a calculated field in your dataset with available years (it can be a copy of the SP list dataset), call it `calculatedYear` and use:

```
=YEAR(Fields!Date.Value)
```

Now create a Year parameter of Intenger data type, and set this settings:

[image]

Where `DataSet15` is the DataSet name that feeds your parameter with the available years.

Then just add another filter in your dataset:

[image]

> Note you will need two datasets one to get the available years and
>   other the dataset you need to filter.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I had something similar except I didn't use my parameter as type integer.  I used text and spelled each month and used this expression: =MonthName(Month(Fields!fieldname.Value)). The issue I'll run into is how will I handle all the data that's in January for 2016, 2017, ... etc. The next logical step I took was to add a year param and followed the same steps but this seems messy. Is there a way to make it more dynamic based on the data? Doesn't look like I can add expressions to the available fields.